# Google analytics api showing Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home2/.../.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am working on a google analytics dashboard which will display marketing campaign results for the customers. I am using google analytics api but I keep getting this error ( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home2/.../.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 388). I searched about the error and found that it is because of a mismatch of the php version between apache server and CLI.my CLI php version used to be 7.1.12 and my apache version was 7.1.14. I upgraded it to 7.1.14 but I am still facing the same error.

Comment: That's a good idea to paste the error line here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the offending line from Arr.php:

```
[$value, $key] = static::explodePluckParameters($value, $key);
```

It seems your PHP server is still running version < 7.1.0 and it doesnt support this array notation

To test it, you can use following code (php 5.x and php < 7.1.0 throws parse error):

```
[$value, $key] = explode("|",'some|thing');
var_dump($value,$key);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, PHP 7.10? What? If you are from the future, please send me lottery numbers.

Comment: ..Sorry again, haven't slept properly today, I meant this array notation was introduced in 7.1.0 I think :))

Comment: You know, OP is not able to test any [$a, $b] with var_dump because he has a "Parse Fatal Error" on the same code right now. I mean, what's new do you want to show him?

Comment: Yeah, agreed, var_dump isn't needed here :)

Comment: what should I add inside the two quotation marks?.. I am novice so please bear with me.

Comment: Old syntax: `list($a, $b) = $array`, new syntax: `[$a, $b] = $array`, you may use `list` instead of brackets if you don't want to update the PHP version and if you are sure that the code don't use inside a lot of new features like this.

Comment: Changing vendor code is a bad practice. Either upgrade the PHP version or downgrade Laravel (but I strongly advise against it)

Comment: I just uplaod a php file contain <?php phpinfo ?> to the host, and found out the php version is 7.0.31. php artisan --version output is (laravel framework 5.7.13). and also php -v output is 7.1.14. I am not sure how to upgrade my server and if it is better to downgrade laravel instead of missing up with the server?

Comment: PHP 7.0.x will stop receiving security patches in 3 weeks (it's End-Of-Life is set to 1st of Jan 2019), so I not upgrading is a really bad idea :)